# How do populate Excel spreadsheet with data from website?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a list of lojban words in an Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

(The numbers on the left are their frequency in the lojban corpus, but that shouldn't be important.)

I've been manually looking up each word on the website http://jbovlaste.lojban.org/ manually and copy and pasting it back into my spreadsheet.

Is there any way I can automate this (at least partially), either with Excel's inbuilt features or VBA scripting?

Comment: It looks like you can manually download the dictionary via XML. I don't know much about VBA but it's a relatively simple operation in Python to compare your Excel sheet's values to the XML file.

Comment: there are different methods for a one time vs something you are going to repeat such as once a month, Then it also matters what you plan to do after you have all the data in excel in the layout you want.  Please add some extra details